# rails 4 with turbolinks and window load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 4.

I'm trying to use this script to show google maps. I got a page with different places and each place got an address. It shows in google maps.
So i'm using pagination and on each page I got 4 places. 4 scripts of gmap.
But this scripts initializes only on page reload (ctrl+R or F5), that's because of turbolinks.

How can i make it work the easiest way?

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= place.latitude %>, <%= place.longitude %>); 
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map-canvas-<%= place.id %>"),
      mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: '<%= place.title %>'
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

that's the script. And div with each map looks like this:

```
<div id="map-canvas-<%= place.id %>"></div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to initialize scripts via turbolinks. Check [this ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks) about turbolinks.

In general, you need to change...

```
jQuery(function() {
  # your script
});
```

...to...

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  # your script
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

All turbo links events you can find [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#events).

### Update for Turbolinks 5

`page:load` has changed to `turbolinks:load`, so instead you want to write:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  # your script
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

You no longer need to specify `$(document).ready();` as `turbolinks:load` does that. For more info, check out the [README](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

Comment: Good answer. Just to let  everyone know, [Turbolinks 5.0beta](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)  is out. `page:load` is now `turbolinks:load`

Comment: Ahhh @RubyRacer, you've just saved me hours

Comment: Also you no longer need to specify $(document).ready(); as turbolinks:load does that